# Bayes Rule Uniform Distribution

Tags: bayesian, uniform-distribution, transform

For Bayes rule, if my likelihood, and prior distribution are both uniform, is my posterior distribution also guaranteed to be uniform?

In addition to this, if I apply some transformation to a uniform distribution such as:

If $\mathbb{x}\sim U[-1,1]$ then is $f(\mathbb{x}) = \mathbb{x} +3\mathbb{x} +4\mathbb{x}^3 $,

then is $f(\mathbb{x})$ guaranteed to be still a valid pdf, so long as I apply a normalising constant to $f(\mathbb{x})$? Could someone correct me if I'm incorrect.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "both"? Uniform has two parameters for min and max - you assume uniform priors for them?

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion there on the notion(s) of uniform distribution(s):

1. if the sampling distribution is uniform and depends on a parameter
   $\theta$, it means that the support of the uniform depends on
   $\theta$, hence that the normalising constant of the density depends
   on $\theta$. Therefore the likelihood is not constant on $\theta$,
   which means that **the posterior is not uniform on $\theta$** under a uniform prior. Obviously, if $f(x|\theta)=a(\theta)$, picking the prior $\pi(\theta)\propto 1/a(\theta)$ will produce a constant posterior.
2. If one applies a transform $f(\cdot)$ to a uniform variate, $f(X)$ is only uniform for a constant Jacobian $\text{d}f/\text{d}x$, which means the transform is linear. This does not work with your polynomial transform. And there is no normalising constant involved.